# Questions on Firefox OS to post here or in Firefox OS Enthusiasts?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know what type of questions with regards to Firefox OS is suitable to post in here?

This is because I have propose a [Firefox OS Enthusiasts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50105/firefox-os-enthusiasts) (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50105/firefox-os-enthusiasts) and I need to define the proposal so that there is no question that might overlap between Superuser and Firefox OS Enthusiasts.

I seem Android, Windows Phone and iPhone stackexchange and was wondering if it would be good to start a Firefox Stackexchange.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

I'd advise to leave Firefox (both the OS and the browser) under Super User's umbrella, so to speak.

**It's not worth splitting Firefox into a new site**, I feel the same *could* be said for Linux or Apple.

Also: Firefox will **always** be on topic here, so even if there is another Stack Exchange for Firefox OS, there will be no reason to move it *unless the original poster specifically asks for it to be moved.* Note that Linux and Apple is still on topic at Super User.

Comment: Firefox OS seems to be [an actual operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_OS) designed for smartphones and tablets, not a browser. Smartphones and tablets are off-topic except insamuch as they interface with a computer, right? (like, is Android on or off topic?)

Comment: @cpast my thoughts still stand, revised to include the OS. Thanks!

Comment: @studiohack, so I can still post Android question here or to Android Enthusiasts depending where I would like to post the particular Android question that I had?

Comment: @studiohack, also, can I assume that a user can post a Firefox OS (a OS designed for smartphones and tablets) question to either Firefox OS Enthusiasts or Superuser depending on that user decision?

Comment: @studiohack, just one more assumption, so, if there is no worth splitting Firefox OS into a new site, would there be such scenario in the future that result a decision to merge all OS related sites (such as Apple and Linux) into Superuser?

Comment: @Jack Per our current FAQ and policy, we only allow Android questions when they're about interfacing with your "regular" PC or Mac running Windows, Linux, or OS X (or similar). The big question is whether we want to open up to all kinds of platforms in the future. Note that our own scope should never depend on what other sites exist. This also means that [apple.SE] and [unix.SE] will never be merged into SU.

Comment: But, since we said we'd accept Windows RT questions, we could probably also accept Firefox OS questions. It'd be a new topic for all of us but I personally don't see a problem with it.

Comment: @slhck and studiohack: I quoted you on a separate discussion, [Are questions about Firefox OS on-topic on Super User?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8361/151741)