# Are questions about Firefox OS on-topic on Super User?

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

**Are questions about [Firefox OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_OS) on-topic on Super User?** Even questions that don’t "[interface with your computer](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)"?

For example:

- How can I change the URL of a Firefox bookmark in Firefox OS?
- [How can I see if an installed app is hosted or packaged?](https://superuser.com/q/798878/151741)

  - (**edit 1:** I created this question as it currently seems that Firefox OS is on-topic; hopefully this will bring more input/votes to this discussion here.)
- How do I get rid of all traces about a particular photo I made?
- Can I see the source code of an installed packaged app when I’m offline?

  - (**edit 2:** created a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/802155/151741))
- Is there a reason not to enable USB access by default?

On the discussion [Questions on Firefox OS to post here or in Firefox OS Enthusiasts?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6253/151741) [studiohack♦ wrote](https://meta.superuser.com/a/6254/151741):

> I'd advise to leave Firefox (both the OS and the browser) under Super User's umbrella […]

and [slhck♦ commented](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6253/questions-on-firefox-os-to-post-here-or-in-firefox-os-enthusiasts#comment16021_6254):

> […] since we said we'd accept Windows RT questions, we could probably also accept Firefox OS questions. It'd be a new topic for all of us but I personally don't see a problem with it.

But I’m not sure if this is decided by these statements?

(FWIW, there is an [Area 51 proposal "Firefox OS"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59192/firefox-os?referrer=DiDmN07LBnwqQRo_of3bPg2), but it’s questionable if it will have success. The [previous proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50105/firefox-os-enthusiasts) failed.)

Comment: The "no mobile devices" line definitely gets more and more blurry all the time...

Comment: If Firefox OS is being used for a desktop OS, is it still a mobile device question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Personally, I say, why not? I don't foresee many problems with it, and it's very likely our audience would be the best to deal with it. Should the proposal go through this time on Area 51, then I think we can re-address it then.

Comment: FWIW, the [mentioned Area51 proposal got closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59192/firefox-os) this month (because it was older than a year).